# Where can I buy kosher Tefillin scrolls?

Tags: product-recommendation, tefilin

Can anyone recommend a place/person to get kosher tefillin? I heard about the fraud with scrolls.

There is no sofer or judaica store near me.

Please include information about *why* you recommend the source that you do.

Comment: Do you mean to have shipped to you, then?

Comment: I don't know what the "the fraud" reference is, but should this be tagged [tag:current-events]?

Comment: Steve Dorfman, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for bringing your question here. Please consider registering your account to gain full access to the features on this site. I look forward to seeing you around!

Comment: In case you also need Tzitzit: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1094/ben-bens-tallit-shop

Comment: @msh210 The fraud referenced has been going on for a while. It's mentioned in Mishnah Berurah (yes, even in the first edition) so it's not exactly current

Comment: @Yitzchak, I have no idea what fraud the asker is referring to and no idea what fraud you're referring to. But I'm curious: how do you know those two are the same?

Comment: @DoubleAA - I would recommend Ben's Tallit Shop to anyone. Nice! I have purchased from him several times and every time was a great experience.

Comment: Keep in mind that a sofer should insert the parashiot into the tefillin.

Answer (score 6):

I have to throw in my link as well [MezuzahStore.com](http://mezuzahstore.com). I mainly recommend it because I own it and therefore can vouch for the quality of the [Tefillin](http://mezuzahstore.com/collections/tefillin) ;)

Comment: While an Advertisement is technically a reason for a Spam Flag around here, +1 for being the best sourced answer here :)

Answer (score 5):

I have friends that have used http://www.hasofer.com/ satisfactorily.

Comment: Also check out http://machonstam.com/

Answer (score 4):

I use Oraita (http://www.mysofer.com) for all of my tefillin/mezuzos needs. They don't list tefillin scrolls on their website (just complete tefillin), but they probably would sell them separately if asked.

Answer (score 4):

I researched this for quite a while as I needed three pairs of tfilin (for different people, at different times). I ended up buying from

- [HaSofer](http://www.hasofer.com/index.htm) in their Jerusalem store, R Flumenbaum is a wonderful person, has a strong reputation and has significant inventory on hand. I asked a few questions and he had answers on the tip of his tongue. Best if you need tfilin quickly
- [stam.net](http://www.stam.net/), after reading R Askotzky's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568712324). He is able to customize batim and klafim to your exact requirements - I went to see him at his home/workshop and he was highly helpful. I waited 3 months for the sofer to write the parshiot
- [Tefillin Beth El,](http://www.en.tefillin.co.il/index.php?homeen=1) with my son before his bar mitsva as they offer educational tours of their factory which demystified tfilin and made the whole experience very pedagogic. I was able to choose the parshiot from a few they had in stock but had to wait a few week for final assembly

Two more resources to mention for those interested in tfilin

- a great [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1600912133) on stam (sifrei Torah, tfilin, mezuzot)
- [an educational movie from TorahLive on tfilin](https://torahlive.com/courses/tefillin-the-ultimate-bond/)

Comment: Only problem with stam.net is that they don't seem to sell Arizal tefillin.

Comment: @ezra worth asking him directly as he has access to many sofrim. But maybe you did this already.

Answer (score 2):

How about [stam.net](http://stam.net)?  My understanding is that R' Askotzky is a highly respected sofer.

Comment: Only problem with stam.net is that they don't seem to sell Arizal tefillin.

Answer (score 2):

I believe everything at http://www.tefillin.biz/ is certified mishmert stam. it's an israeli company.

Answer (score 2):

R' Melech Michaels ([mezuzadepot.com](http://mezuzadepot.com)) is a close talmid of R' Avram Tzvi HaLevi Wosner, who is the leading authority for the Vaad Mishmereth Stam in the US. I purchased new parshiot through him over the summer and the k'tav is beautiful. He also spends a fair amount of time talking things over with you, so that is also a great benefit.

Answer (score 0):

[Chevras HaSofrim](https://www.chevrashasofrim.com/) sells complete sets of tefillin but also has a unique "tefillin builder" which allows to custom create your tefillin based on your preferences and needs. It's quite a neat website.

You can purchase [the scrolls](https://www.chevrashasofrim.com/product-category/tefillin-accessories/parshios-scrolls/) without having to purchase battim and straps.