# One mezuzah, two outside doors -- which is preferred?

Tags: halacha, priorities, mezuzah

In a house with two outside entrances, what is the halacha if you only have one mezuzah?  Is there a priority in entrances, or does the occupant choose?  (Yes, one should acquire a second mezuzah, but until then...)

I just moved into a new home and only have one mezuzah. I understand it should be placed on the door to the main entrance of the home. However, the main entrance is only used maybe 10% of the time. 90% of the time I am entering and leaving through the door that leads from my home into the garage. I want to be able to see and touch the mezuzah upon entering and leaving my home, but maybe I'm required to put it on the other door instead.

Comment: You may be interested in https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17570/759 or https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17081/759

Comment: Eric, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for bringing your question here.  We avoid giving (or giving the appearance of giving) *p'sak* answers here, which is why your question was put on hold.  I've made some edits to ask the halacha question instead of the "what should I personally do" question, and reopened.  You can see my changes by clicking on the "edited" link above my name under the post, and can [edit] further yourself by clicking on "edit" if you like.  Best wishes in your new home, and may you be blessed with the resources to acquire mezuzot for all your doors in the future.

Comment: @monic is this not a dupe of the q I linked to about prioritizing doorways?

Comment: @DoubleAA that question takes as given that the first one goes to the "main" door and asks about interior doors; this question asks about determining the "main" door (placement or usage).